# Re-using the data brought by mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a a table named books containg fields as

> book_id | title | author | summary

With the code below I query db and display list of book titles and authors. After listing, whenever a title link of a book clicked I want to display the summary of that book without querying the db again...   How can I accomplish this without re-querying db and just using the data stored in $books_query_result?

```
$books_query="SELECT * FROM books";
$books_query_result=mysql_query($books_query) or die("Could not get list".mysql_error());

echo "<table><tr>";
echo "<td>";


  while($list=mysql_fetch_array($books_query_result)){
    echo "<A href=\"" .$list['book_id'] ."\"> ". $list['title']. "</a>";
    echo $list['author']."<br>";
  }


# Now I want to reset and re-use mysql_fetch_array

  mysql_data_seek($books_query_result, 0); 
  $summary=mysql_fetch_array($books_query_result);


  echo "</td>";
  echo "<td>";

#display summary here


  echo "<td>";
  echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: Don't do this, just store your fetched data in an array which you can reuse lter.

Comment: The second time you have not the same resultset as before: books vs. $selectcompany_query_result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for resetting and iterating $books_query_result again, than you should use mysql_data_seek($books_query_result, 0); instead mysql_data_seek($selectcompany_query_result, 0).

Just prepare the array inside while loop and use it anywhere later

```
while($list=mysql_fetch_array($books_query_result)){
    //echo "<A href=\"" .$list['book_id'] ."\"> ". $list['title']. "</a>";
    //echo $list['author']."<br>";

    // prepare array here
    $resultArray[] = $list;
}
```

Now use the $resultArray.

Comment: Oopps, it was typing mistake. I edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: After that do we need javascript to display summary when a title clicked?

Comment: @mustafa, yes you can than on use the array as you wish, same as we are using other php arrays multiple times

Answer (score 1):

Print all the data like it should be visible and the summaries into div's with `style="display:none". Then on the link add the call to the function which is for toggling visibility: http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/12/how-to-hide-and-show-your-div/. Make sure you also add that function into your javascript. This way your data is always there and you won't need to reload it.